# Backpack laravel 'type'=>'select', работает, но записывает в базу без него

Tags: php, laravel, phpmyadmin

Релативный селект работает [image]  Но он не записывает выбранный элемент в insert [image] , name у селекта в форме верный (usl_id)

backpack create продукта скажем -
[image] , [image]

Модель категории - [image]

Сталкивался кто нибудь с подобным? Почему он не дабавляет колонку в insert запрос?  [image]
Помогите пожалуйста я все перекопал, спасибо вам большое! <3 <3 <3

Comment: код и текст ошибки нужно вставлять текстом, а не картинками

Answer (score -1):

'pivot'=>true, не нужен....